# C#- A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'InetTimeManager.MainForm.IniPath'

Tags: c#, field, initializer, non-static

I am fairly new to C# and I am currently writing a program and this program should be able to write to an Ini File, that is why I used this class

```
public class IniFile
{
    public string path;

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
      string key, string val, string filePath);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
      string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
      int size, string filePath);

    public IniFile(string INIPath)
    {
        path = INIPath;
    }

    public void IniWriteValue(string Section, string Key, string Value)
    {
        WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, this.path);
    }

    public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key, string defaultvalue)
    {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
        int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp, 255, this.path);
        if (temp.ToString() == "")
        {
            return defaultvalue;
        }
        return temp.ToString();
    }
}
```

To write and read IniFiles.
I understood that you need to call that class from an Instance, that  is exactly what I did:

```
IniFile InstanceIniFile = new IniFile(IniPath);
```

To understand my programm, I have three files, one Program.cs which contains the class, one FirstStart.cs which uses the InstanceIniFile and everything works fine, the problem is now that I also want to read and write Ini Files with the MainForm.cs but whereever I put the `IniFile InstanceIniFile = new IniFile(IniPath);`
I always get this error:

```
Error   1   A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'InetTimeManager.MainForm.IniPath'   D:\Extras\Programmieren\C#\InetTimeManager\InetTimeManager\MainForm.cs  20  47  InetTimeManager
```

, IniPath is always the same variable in each file. I also made sure that it exists, in case you are wondering, IniPath is just this:

```
string IniPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "config.ini");
```

So I am not really sure what I am doing wrong and I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you very much
Fliwatt

Comment: you didn't list `MainForm` where the property for `IniPath` would be defined, but it appears you defined a local variable, not a Public Property

Comment: So what -in code- am I supposed to do then?

Comment: You can't do that in an initializer. Create your class member `IniFile InstanceIniFile;` and then initialize it in the constructor `this.InstanceIniFile = new IniFile(IniPath);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366964/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-property)

Comment: Sorry that I don't really get it, I have the feeling that I am messing everything up here, this is what I did:
`string IniPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "config.ini");
        InstanceIniFile = new IniFile(IniPath);
        int Hours = InstanceIniFile.IniReadValue("main", "timeHours", null);

        static System.Windows.Forms.Timer NetworkSpeedTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        public IniFile InstanceIniFile()
        {
            this.InstanceIniFile = new IniFile(IniPath);
        }`
And now I am getting new errors, I think I did it wrong